# How to make spaCy ignore new line characters when finding noun_chunks

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, text-processing

I don't know why this happens. A new line character I feel like should be ignored but outputs of `doc.noun_chunks` sometimes change when newline (`\n`) characters are replaced with whitespace. How do I make it so that spacy treats them the same, or as if there is no newline characters? It is too much hassle to just remove them, needs some backlog work to trace them back to their original lines.
E.g.

```py
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")
print(list(nlp(' '.join(['Krüger', 'Finest', 'Selection', 'versch.', 'Sorten', 'Je', '300-g-dose'])).noun_chunks))
# output: [Krüger Finest Selection, Sorten]
print(list(nlp('\n'.join(['Krüger', 'Finest', 'Selection', 'versch.', 'Sorten', 'Je', '300-g-dose'])).noun_chunks))
# output: [\nSorten]
```

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: @Raqib I added it. I don't know if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: so @Raqib, any luck?

Answer (score 2):

spaCy training data doesn't include newline characters, and whitespace besides normal spaces gets treated as tokens, so weird whitespace can cause unusual results.

If you don't care about newlines or other whitespace, normalize them before passing to text to spaCy. A simple way to do this is to convert them all to normal spaces.